# maven-compiler-plugin in parent pom

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

I am facing issue in setting java compiler version for the parent-child pom files. I added maven-compiler-plugin in child pom with version 1.7 and noticed that the java version changed from default 1.5 to 1.7 for child module and the parent project is still with 1.5. Then, I moved the compiler plugin from child pom to parent pom. Expected that the compiler version will be changed to 1.7 for both parent and child maven modules. But strangely no changes observed, the child module is still with 1.7 and the parent project is 1.5. I performed 'maven- > update project' from eclipse IDE. but no use. FYI : Building the parent-child projects is working fine with no issues.  Any help?  Here are my parent and child POMs

---

### PARENT POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mymaven.parentpom.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ParentPOMProj</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>ParentPOMProj</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>ParentPOMProj</finalName>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>


    <modules>
        <module>ModuleOne</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

---

### CHILD POM

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mymaven.parentpom.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>ParentPOMProj</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.mymaven.parentpom.example.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>ModuleOne</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ModuleOne</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>ModuleOne</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

### -----------------------------------------------------

[image: IDE Image]

Comment: Have you already clicked on the link `Change project compliance and JRE to 1.7` which is displayed in your screenshot. This is an Eclipse project setting.

Comment: I could do that from IDE settings. But, my main idea is to control this through POM, but not through any of IDE settings.

Comment: But you can't control the IDE from the POM. You are working in the IDE anyway.

Comment: Sorry kornisb. I am not convenience with your suggestion. If I cant control this through POM, then whats the need of maven-compiler-plugin?

Comment: Run the compile from command line `mvn compile` and check if it's ok. If it's ok your Meven settings are ok. If it's still not compilling in Eclipse it's for sure not a Maven setting. Isn't it?

Comment: In response to a previous comment, if the Maven project has the correct settings then the M2E plugin should update the IDE settings accordingly i.e. if I set the java version to 8 and then run Maven > Update Project in Eclipse, the Eclipse settings will update automatically.

Comment: @SubOptimal: I tried mvn compile though successfully compiled but my issue is not resolved. Now I have a serous question, what is the need of maven-compiler-plugin, if I cant customize java version through POM?

Comment: @Alan Hay : If your comment is true, then, how could I be able to set v1.7 for child module without doing all this extra stuff?

Comment: I have given you an answer and in the comment to that answer have advised you why it **still** doesn't work. Follow the clear instructions provided and run maven update on all projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching further, I understood that the java version in maven-compiler-plugin in parent pom applies to the child POMs but not to the parent itself. Basically, most of the time, it is not recommend to keep any source code in parent project, it is barely to handle all the build configuration for the child modules. Here are the updated POMS :

---

### PARENT POM

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.mymaven.parentpom.example</groupId>
<artifactId>ParentPOMProj</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>ParentPOMProj</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>ParentPOMProj</finalName>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>


<modules>
    <module>ModuleOne</module>
</modules>
```

---

### CHILD POM

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mymaven.parentpom.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ParentPOMProj</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.mymaven.parentpom.example.module</groupId>
<artifactId>ModuleOne</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ModuleOne</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

[image]

Comment: I hardly believe that you can compile the sources in `ParentPOMProj/src/main/java` with `mvn compile`. As the packaging is `<packaging>**pom**</packaging>` Maven won't compile them. Have you done the `right click on Project -> Maven -> Update project` in Eclipse? In Eclipse Luna you are not even able to change the Java compiler settings for the `ParentPOMProj`.

Comment: I am using eclipse MARS v4.5.2. I did 'update project' on parent project and could even perform mvn compile with build success. As I stated in my response, it is not recommended to keep java source files in the parent pom. Parent project is to keep the build configuration that is needed for the child modules. You can't compile sources in ParentPOMProj/src/main/java. I hope this clears you doubt.

Comment: `You can't compile sources in ParentPOMProj/src/main/java.` that's what I said. :-)

Comment: @SubOptimal.::   Agreed    ... :)

Answer (score 23):

In the parent you need to define it in `<pluginManagement/>` rather than `<plugins/>`

https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management

> pluginManagement: is an element that is seen along side plugins.
>   Plugin Management contains plugin elements in much the same way,
>   except that rather than configuring plugin information for this
>   particular project build, **it is intended to configure project builds
>   that inherit from this one**

```
<build>
    <finalName>ParentPOMProj</finalName>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

As mentioned in the docs, **the child project also needs to reference the plugin**:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- inherits config from parent: can override if required -->
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Update your question to show the new content of both poms.

Comment: Updated my question. Please take a look.

Comment: So you actually have code in the parent pom. This is not normally the case. You need then to add the <plugins/> block in parent as well. However I would suggest that you do not add code in the parent. Note that it has packaging type POM as opposed to JAR so nothing will get compiled on maven build.

Comment: My idea is to keep the maven-compiler-plugin in one pom, so it applies to all the modules and eliminate the duplication. If there are multiple modules , what is the best way of handling this situation?

Comment: The only way to do it is as I have suggested as **clearly** stated in the documentation.As mentioned in the docs, **the child project also needs to reference the plugin:**

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. I appreciate it alan.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the compliance of the project. Right click on the project in the Project Explorer of Eclipse, then go to Properties, and set it as shown on the picture (you can also set it to version 1.7 if the proper JDK is installed):

[image]

Comment: I want to control this through pom. I believe, this is the purpose of using maven-compiler-plugin after all.